# How to drop decimal place on numbers in a JSON array?

Tags: shell, json, floating-point

What shell command in a `bash` script could be issued to efficiently strip all the decimal places from the numbers in a JSON file such as this:

```
    [
        {
            "IMSKU": "1000001", 
            "AttributeID": 7332.0, 
            "Value": "McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention for Desktops safeguards your business against complex security threats that may otherwise be unintentionally introduced or allowed by desktops and laptops. Host Intrusion Prevention for Desktops is easy to deploy, configure, and manage.", 
            "Unit": null, 
            "StoredValue": null, 
            "StoredUnit": null, 
            "Name": "Marketing text", 
            "Format": "1", 
            "Position": "1", 
            "Group_Name": "Basic Specification", 
            "AGGroup_Position": 0.0, 
            "Product_Hierarchy": 15198001453.0
        }, 
        {
            "IMSKU": "1000001", 
            "AttributeID": 7343.0, 
            "Value": "May 2013", 
            "Unit": null, 
            "StoredValue": null, 
            "StoredUnit": null, 
            "Name": "PI Date", 
            "Format": "1", 
            "Position": "1", 
            "Group_Name": "PI DATE", 
            "AGGroup_Position": 1.0, 
            "Product_Hierarchy": 15198001453.0
        }, 
        {
            "IMSKU": "1000001", 
            "AttributeID": 7344.0, 
            "Value": "McAfee", 
            "Unit": null, 
            "StoredValue": "0.00", 
            "StoredUnit": null, 
            "Name": "Brand Name", 
            "Format": "3", 
            "Position": "1", 
            "Group_Name": "PRODUCT", 
            "AGGroup_Position": 2.0, 
            "Product_Hierarchy": 15198001453.0
        }
    ]
```

So that

```
"AttributeID":  7344.0
```

would become

```
"AttributeID":  7344
```

for example, and so forth.

Comment: Note that _there is no difference semantically_; JSON only has a single "number" type.

Comment: that's not an array

Comment: @Jasen I see.  So what would you call it...?

Comment: https://www.json.org/json-en.html - curly brackets mean it's an object.

Comment: @Jasen I humbly defer to your knowledge; if this warrants a correction in the original title and post, feel free to exercise your editorial privileges.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just running it through the identity filter with `jq` reformats the numbers that has a `.0` decimal as integers:

```
$ jq . file.json
[
  {
    "IMSKU": "1000001",
    "AttributeID": 7332,
    "Value": "McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention for Desktops safeguards your business against complex security threats that may otherwise be unintentionally introduced or allowed by desktops and laptops. Host Intrusion Prevention for Desktops is easy to deploy, configure, and manage.",
    "Unit": null,
    "StoredValue": null,
    "StoredUnit": null,
    "Name": "Marketing text",
    "Format": "1",
    "Position": "1",
    "Group_Name": "Basic Specification",
    "AGGroup_Position": 0,
    "Product_Hierarchy": 15198001453
  },

(etc.)
```

If there are numbers with decimals that are not zero, and you want to remove these too, use

```
jq '(.. | select(type == "number" )) |= floor' file.json
```

This would apply the `floor` function on all numbers whatsoever in the data, rounding them down to the closest integer.

To also investigate whether there are strings that contain digits after a dot at the very end, and remove these digits (and the dot):

```
jq '(.. | select(type == "string")) |= sub("\\.[0-9]+$"; "")' file.json
```

The affected entries would still be strings and are not converted to a numerical type.

Comment: What about for `"StoredValue": "0.00",`?  `jq . file.json` seems to leave these untouched?

Comment: @ptrcao When you said numbers, I only considered the numbers. `"0.00"` is technically a string.  Do you want to modify these too and at the same time change the type of them to number?  This may impact any program reading the data.

Comment: Yes, for this example, suppose I wanted also to drop the decimals on instances of `"0.00"`.  If later that creates problems, I can just not use this part of the solution.  Although you are technically right, it's a string and not a part of the original question.  Let's consider it for educational purposes.

Comment: @ptrcao Sorry, I was called away. See updated answer.

Comment: This is where I need to be careful.  For example, I would not want to strip the decimal places in such scenarios as `"USB 3.0"`, or `"Value": "3.0"` where `"Unit": "GHz"`, as these are situations where the `.0` us untentional and I would want to keep it as such.  I cannot identify all such adverse instances in a finite or knowing way.  Suggestions?

Comment: @ptrcao Then it would be safest to only modify the values corresponding to the _specific keys_ that you know you want to modify rather than relying on heuristics. It's 1.30AM here and I need to sleep, but I might get back to this tomorrow and write an example for that too.